# TimePicker mui-x taking up entire width of screen when clicked on. How do I set the width?

Tags: reactjs, width, timepicker, sizing, mui-x

I've pretty much looked everywhere and have tried every solution posted I could find but nothing works. Can someone help me?

Screenshot:
[image: Here is a screenshot of the behavior when the time picker is opened]

Here is my code:

```js
<Controller
  name="startTime"
  control={control}
  rules={{ validate: validateTime }}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <TimePicker
      {...field}
      value={field?.value || null}
      format="HH:mm"
      name="startTime"
      ampm={false}
      minutesStep={15}
      label="24 hours"
      className="time-picker"
      slotProps={{
        textField: {
          sx: {
            borderRadius: 6,
            fieldset: { borderRadius: 6 },
            [`.${OutlinedInputClasses.root}`]: {
              height: 80,
              width: 300,
            },
            '& .MuiInputLabel-root': { lineHeight: 3 },
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

Comment: what if the purpose of the extra classname="time-picker"

Comment: I had to create a separate time field to retro fit the front-end to a legacy Java application that was originally designed with separate columns for date and time. Otherwise I would have used a combined date/time control.

I suppose I could have a date/time element and pull the date and time portions separately from it and populate the database accordingly?